Why React-native-face-detection not working on IOS and just return blank array / []?
This is my react native info
System:
OS: macOS 14.1.1
CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 114.23 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell:
version: "5.9"
path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node:
version: 20.10.0
path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm:
version: 10.2.3
path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/npm
Watchman:
version: 2024.08.05.00
path: /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods:
version: 1.15.2
path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms:
- DriverKit 23.5
- iOS 17.5
- macOS 14.5
- tvOS 17.5
- visionOS 1.2
- watchOS 10.5
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Xcode:
version: 15.4/15F31d
path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: Not Found
Ruby:
version: 2.6.10
path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
"@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
react:
installed: 18.2.0
wanted: 18.2.0
react-native:
installed: 0.73.0
wanted: 0.73.0
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
"*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false

faceDetectionMethod = async() =>{

const imagePath = this.state.imageCamera;
const options = {
landmarkMode: FaceDetectorLandmarkMode.ALL,
contourMode: FaceDetectorContourMode.ALL,
};
const faces = await FaceDetection.processImage(imagePath, options);

if(faces.length === 0){
this.setState({isWajah:false});
this.setState({isVisibleWajah:true});
}else{

this.setState({isWajah:true});

this.setState({isVisibleWajah:false});

}
}

this method is use for facedetection and just return [] / blank array
